# getting the weather for my current location, android

Tags: android, weather

I want to make an android application to get weather forecast using openweathermap I from the website, I see that the URL is written like this :

[api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=35&lon=139&cnt=10&mode=json]

I want to add my current location as longitude and latitude instead of constant values; I got the longitude and latitude of my current location; but I don't know how to add them into the URL.

can I use val[longitude]+val[latitude]??

Comment: Where do you have your locations stored? In array val?

Comment: @ArturSkowronski just assumption that I have; I actually don't know how to put longitude and latitude in the URL

Comment: You say you're making the application on Android, but are you using Phone Gap and therefore javascript? or are you using Java on Android?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I am using Java on Android

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java.net, yes you can do it just in plain string as:

```
 URL urla = new URL("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat="+val[latitude]+"&lon="+val[longitude]+"&cnt=10&mode=json");
```

I highly suggest to add `org.apache.http` to your project. It will make doing api call far easier than in vanilla Java.

Do you have any experience in Java? Cause I don't know if I understood your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the latitude and longitude are doubles for coordinates like [this](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=57&lon=-2.15).

You'd write:

```
double lat, lon;
...
String newURL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&cnt=10&mode=json";
```

That being said, this is a very basic question. I'd recommend you do the following java tutorials at

http://javala.cs.tut.fi

*That system is able to grade you and I'd suggest you try to get at least 90% of the points on it.*

You could try using the `org.apache.http` library as suggested by Arthur, but I'm afraid you might not get far if you haven't memorized the simpler Java constructs yet.